# SQL Server query that asks to return to most recent date customer log in to the system

Tags: sql-server

I have an interview question that looks like this:

Table `User` has columns:

```
user_id ,
name ,
phone_num
```

Table `UserHistory` has columns:

```
user_id ,
date ,
action
```

Write a SQL query that returns the name, phone number and most recent date for any user that has logged in over the last 30 days (you can tell a user has logged in if the action field in `UserHistory` is set to "logged_on").

I am a newbie to SQL , I wrote a query as below:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT user_id 
      FROM User 
      JOIN User_History ON user.user_id = User_History.user_id)
WHERE 
    MAX(DATEDIFF(day, date, getdate()) BETWEEN 1 AND 30

SELECT  
    u.Name, u.phone_number 
FROM 
    #temp t 
JOIN 
    User u ON u.user_id =  t.user_ID
```

I am not provided with data for the table, can someone take a look and shed some insights on it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler version would have been something like:

```
SELECT u.name, u.phone_num, MAX(date) as MostRecentLogon
FROM user u
JOIN UserHistory uh on u.user_id = uh.user_id
WHERE uh.action = "logged_on"
AND uh.date >= DATEADD(d, -30, GETDATE())
GROUP BY u.name, u.phone_num
```